# How to fetch the last row in MySQL in THIS scenario?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have the table - *checkdate*

The Structure is ...

```
Curr_date 

 150120
 160120
 170120
 180120
```

( Date format is ***DDMMYY*** )

Only Single column is there which is the **'Primary Key'**

Now I want to fetch the LATEST DATE or CURRENT DATE saved in the table ( Which ***will not*** always be the last row )

Example:
The Date latest added date is : 010122

Then, the record will show like...

```
Curr_date

010122        <--- The Latest date is on the top
150120
160120
170120
```

> Now how to fetch the Last Added Row in MySQL ? 
>   In this Scenario ?

( Note : `select TOP 1 * from table_name order by Id desc` , doesn't work... And also I want to work without ID column... )

EDITED : The Datatype is String

Comment: Can you try using this, order it by Curr_date -> select * from table_name order by Curr_date desc limit 1

Comment: It will definately work if you have given correct datatype to your column in mysql table schema @KAKAKAKI

Comment: So actualy the exact question here was how to convert string to date because the selected answer select's them all and orders them by converted date and the correct answer would be something more like: `select date_col
from test 
order by STR_TO_DATE(date_col,'%d%m%Y') desc
limit 1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the data type of curr_date is string. Following query will work for you.

```
select curr_date
       , STR_TO_DATE(curr_date,'%d%m%Y') 
from test 
order by STR_TO_DATE(curr_date,'%d%m%Y') desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you split your string into its component `YY`, `MM` and `DD` parts you can order by each of them descending (in year, month, date order) and get the latest value:

```
SELECT *
FROM dates
ORDER BY RIGHT(Curr_date, 2) DESC, SUBSTR(Curr_date, 3, 2) DESC, LEFT(Curr_date, 2) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
Curr_date
180120
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7b49533a1327e594f8638987d099dc0d)

Comment: Hi @Nick, this will work if the column is int but when it is varchar it will not: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8d7dc17fbbfee3bab2a7b424c3ff18f2

Comment: @VBoka you are attempting to insert an integer into a varchar column and when it gets parsed the leading 0 is stripped. Make the values strings and it works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2a8e22028ac2b10c5dec10bdc57610df

Comment: @VBoka no problems. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a date column shouldn't this work:

```
SELECT MAX(Curr_date) FROM table_name
```

Comment: No, that wont... as I have explained it will show the bigger number first. But for us the latest is 010122 which is smaller than 110120. That won't work

Comment: I do not understand, is it a number or is it a date type ?

Comment: That's String. @VBoka

Comment: @KAKAKAKI well... that should be the first thing in the question to say :)

Answer (score 1):

Both `max` and `group by` can take a complete expression, which you could use to rejigger your string into something which is properly sorted, either using string manipulation or parsing to a proper date.

That aside, you should burn the entire thing to the ground and fire whoever designed it if it was built any later than the 90s. Both storing years as 2 digits and storing things in DMY are known terrible ideas.